# ruby elegant way to reduce similar codes when assign attributes

Tags: ruby, variable-assignment

I want to assign many attributes to a person's name, if the attribute is empty then update it, but if the attribute already has value then skip it. The codes looks like this:

```
self.first = first_parsed unless self.first
self.middle = middle_parsed unless self.middle
self.last = last_parsed unless self.last
self.title = title_parsed unless self.title
self.suffix = suffix_parsed unless self.suffix
```

Is there any elegant way to do this to avoid duplicate codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%w(first middle last title suffix).each do |m|
  self.send("#{m}=",eval("#{m}_parsed")) unless self.send(m)
end
```

Short code to test :

```
class Foo
  attr_accessor :first,:middle
  def meth(first_parsed,middle_parsed)
    %w(first middle).each do |m|
      self.send("#{m}=",eval("#{m}_parsed")) unless self.send(m)
    end
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
foo.meth(11,'wax')
foo.first # => 11
foo.middle # => "wax"
```

Comment: In the example `eval`uation of an argument passed to send just lacks a sense ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
%w[ first middle last title suffix ].each do |a|
  send("#{a}=", send("#{a}_parsed")) unless send(a)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically, in Ruby we'd do this using:

```
self.first ||= first_parsed
self.middle ||= middle_parsed
self.last ||= last_parsed
self.title ||= title_parsed
self.suffix ||= suffix_parsed
```

If I was going to do it a little more dynamically I'd do something like:

```
class SomeClass

  def initialize(first_name=nil, middle_name=nil, last_name=nil, title=nil, suffix=nil)
    @first_name, @middle_name, @last_name, @title, @suffix = first_name, middle_name, last_name, title, suffix
  end

  def update(first_parsed, middle_parsed, last_parsed, title_parsed, suffix_parsed)
    {
      :first_name  => first_parsed,
      :middle_name => middle_parsed,
      :last_name   => last_parsed,
      :title       => title_parsed,
      :suffix      => suffix_parsed
    }.each{ |k, v|
      instance_var = "@#{ k }"
      self.instance_variable_set(instance_var, v) unless self.instance_variable_get(instance_var)
    }
  end

end
```

Using it:

```
some_class_instance = SomeClass.new('foo', 'bar')
some_class_instance
# => #<SomeClass:0x007fcb030941a8
#     @first_name="foo",
#     @last_name=nil,
#     @middle_name="bar",
#     @suffix=nil,
#     @title=nil>

some_class_instance.update(
  *%w[
    new_first
    new_middle
    new_last
    new_title
    new_suffix
  ]
)

some_class_instance
# => #<SomeClass:0x007fcb030941a8
#     @first_name="foo",
#     @last_name="new_last",
#     @middle_name="bar",
#     @suffix="new_suffix",
#     @title="new_title">
```

I prefer to use some sort of visual mapping, which is why the hash of symbols to variables is there. It's possible to do that more dynamically using string parsing, but that can lead to maintenance problems when some part of the algorithm is messing up and the only way you can tell is by printing inside a loop. Using a table like that makes it very easy to search for particular kev/value relationships.

The problem is, by the time we generate code to dynamically do this, we could have already written a simple `||=` based block, and moved on. Debugging time would be reduced, it'd be very obvious what affects what, all of which improves maintainability. So, I'm not sure that being more dynamic actually buys anything useful in the long run. It's one of those trade-offs we make often when writing code.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i would do

```
["first", "middle", "last", "title", "suffix"].map do |method|
  self.send("#{method}=", send("#{method}_parsed")) unless self.send(method) 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

`instance variable set` could help here:

```
class Person
  def some_setter_method
    %w(first middle last title suffix).each do |attr|
      unless instance_variable_get "@#{attr}"
        instance_variable_set "@#{attr}", method(#{attr}_parsed).call
      end        
    end
  end
end
```

I try to avoid `send`s as it calls methods regardless of it's scope state (private public protected).

Comment: in that case you can use [`public_send`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send) also :)